# Why comparison not working in if condition in python?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, arraylist

Q1. Given an array of ints, return True if 6 appears as either the first or last element in the array. The array will be length 1 or more.

```
#first_last6([1, 2, 6]) → True
#first_last6([6, 1, 2, 3]) → True
#first_last6([13, 6, 1, 2, 3]) → False

#Code
my_list = []
in_list = list(map(int, input("Enter a multiple value: ").split()))
for num in in_list:
    my_list.append(num)
if (my_list[0:] == 6 or my_list[:-1] == 6):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

code is working well but if the condition not working while else is working well like if we accessing the indexing "in_list[2]" in the else statement it will give the right answer. then why if condition is not working?

Comment: You don't need the `:` in your indexes. Print out what `my_list[0:]` and `my_list[:-1]` is giving you to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `:`.

That's the `slice` notation and the result of a slice is a list, not an element of that list.

```
my_list = [6, 1, 2, 3]
print(my_list[0:], my_list[:-1]) # slice list
print(my_list[0],  my_list[-1])  # access list item by index
```

Output:

```
[6, 1, 2, 3] [6, 1, 2]
6 3
```